# Symbolize line based on attributes

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to use PolyLineDecorator with Leaflet but I've hit a snag that I can't figure out even forgoing PolyLineDecorator when it comes to symbolizing a path/line based on attribute data.

```
var polyline = L.polyline([...]).addTo(map);
var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
    patterns: [
        // defines a pattern of 10px-wide dashes, repeated every 20px on the line
        {offset: 0, repeat: 20, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 10})}
    ]
}).addTo(map);
```

Works great for me however, I have 20 lines in a single GeoJSON file and i'd like to symbolize the lines based on the Name field in the JSON file. I can't seem to find an example anywhere covering this. Can someone point me to any relevant examples or documentation? I feel like there has to be a way vs exporting each line as its own GeoJSON file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use GeoJson [`onEachFeature()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) method for this. Let's asume that your `geoJson` structure is:

```
var geojsonFeatures = [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Trail 1",
   },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Trail 2",
   },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
  }      
];
```

You can access feature's name properties by `feature.properties.name`:

```
L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties.name === '') {
      L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
        patterns: [
          {offset: 0, repeat: 20, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 10})}
       ]
      }).addTo(map);
    } else {
      L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
        patterns: [
          {offset: 0, repeat: 30, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 20})}
       ]
      }).addTo(map);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am confused a little bit in terms of how to symbolize, for example, Name='Trail 1' and Name='Trail 2' where Id like each symbolized differently based on their name. Thanks again, sorry i am very new to this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't  understand what you meant. What are `Name='Trail 1'` and `Name='Trail 2'`? Properties fro GeoJson features?

Comment: apologies. yes, NAME is a field in the geojson file and id like to symbolize each line differently based on their unique entry in the NAME field of the geojson file. Thanks again for helping I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank  you Lazarev. You've helped me a lot.  I have a much better understanding on how this all gets put together now.